# "Tuple object not callable" when inspecting the result of pygame.key.get_pressed()

Tags: python, pygame, tuples

This is my code where I get the error:

```
# main loop
while True:
    events()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not keys(K_SPACE): continue

    if player_y <= platform_y <= player_y + falling_velocity:
        player_y = platform_y
    else:
        player_y += falling_velocity

    pygame.draw.circle(DS, WHITE, (player_y, player_x - 25), 25, 0)
    pygame.draw.line(DS, WHITE, (0, platform_y), (W, platform_y), 1)

    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    DS.fill(BLACK)
```

I think the error is in this line of code:

```
if not keys(K_SPACE): continue

Error: 
tuple object not callable
```

Comment: As the error says, `keys` isn't a function. Do you mean `if K_SPACE not in keys:?`

Comment: Or perhaps `not keys[K_SPACE]` ?

Comment: @Kingsley Since `keys` is a tuple, not a dictionary, that seems unlikely.

Comment: @Barmar - Python `type()` might call it a tuple, but that's the standard way of using results from `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.  The clause `not keys[pygame.K_SPACE]` is perfectly valid.  Probably it's more than *only* a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a sequence of of boolean values representing the state of every key.

> ```
> keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
> ```

Regardless if the return value is a list or a tuple, then elements can be get by [Subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-subscription) (`keys[K_SPACE]`):

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if not keys[K_SPACE]: continue
```

Note, `keys(K_SPACE)` is a [Call](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls). And `keys` would have to be a callable object like a function.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest changing this:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if not keys(K_SPACE): continue
```

to:

```
keys = ''
while (str(keys) == '' or keys == None): keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

Comment: It looks like he wants to wait for the space key to be pressed. I think your code is waiting for any key.

Comment: Why convert `keys` to a string? Just check its length `while keys is None or len(keys) == 0:`

Comment: Did you down vote my answer just for that?!! I'm supposed to give him a hint not to write the exact code for him and your code is wrong because it will give an error since you didn't initialize keys..that's why I wrote keys = ''

Comment: Oh then I apologize then. Sorry about that :-)